# Golden Layout + Angular2 RC5 - Unable to use ViewContainerRef to dynamically create component

Tags: javascript, angular, golden-layout

I am trying to dynamically create the component to register in Golden Layout. Eg,

```
    @ViewChild('placeholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.myLayout.registerComponent('testComponent', (container, componentState) => {
        //Create an empty div on the container

        container.getElement().html("<div #placeholder></div>");
        this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TestComponent);
        this.cmpRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
        this.cmpRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        GlDirective.componentCount++;
    });
    }
```

However , because viewContainerRef is referring to ViewChild that only gets created now , it is always undefined. How can we create a component in RC5 that uses dynamically added div like the one above. I used @Günter Zöchbauer 's answer on [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components) to derive to this. However unsure on how this can be achieved with Golden Layout which needs the DOM to be generated on the fly. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported.

Something like `#placeholder` in

```
container.getElement().html("<div #placeholder></div>");
```

will just be added to the browser and not recognized or processed in any way by Angular2 (except sanitization for security purposes).

A template variable can only be created by adding it statically to a components template.

Comment: As per http://plnkr.co/edit/tUQOev?p=preview we could load added div using DCL which is deprecated now . Any idea how can this be acheived ?

Comment: I know that DCL supported CSS selectors and no, I don't know if there is a way to do this with currently available APIs :-/

Comment: The only way i can make this work is to use DynamicComponentLoader , however not sure if that's the correct way

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated since quite some while and AFAIK already removed entirely from the source code.